# Consulta many to many Net Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, net

Tengo estas 3 tablas: Personas - Foro - PersonasForo

Personas

```
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<PersonasForo> PForo{ get; set; }
}
```

Foro

```
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<PersonasForo> PForo{ get; set; }
}
```

PersonasForo

```
    {
    public int Personas Id { get; set; }
    public Personas Personas { get; set; }
    public int Foro Id { get; set; }
    public Foro Foro { get; set; }
}
```

Quiero una consulta que me devuelva las Personas que estan en el foro "Stack", la consulta que intento me devuelve unb List (PersonasForo) pero yo quiero un List (Personas)

```
return await _db.PersonasForo.Where(p => p.Foro.Name == "Stack").ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Debes añadir la estructura de Personas, Foro y PersonasForo para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Una duda, si haces _db.PersonasForo.Where(...) creo que es normal que te devuelva un List de PersonasForo, no lo puedes hacer así? _db.Personas.Where(...)

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano si podria hacerlo asi pero no se como llegar a meterle la condición

Comment: @Marc modificada mi pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es obtener todas las `Personas` que estén dentro de `PersonasForo` que estén dentro del `Foro` `'Stack'`, por lo que tienes que obtener del listado `Personas` lo que buscas.

Creo que lo que buscas es lo siguiente:

```
return await _db.Personas.Where(x => _db.PersonasForo.Any(p => p.Foro.Name == "Stack" && p.Personas == x)).ToList();
```

Comment: exacto eso era lo que necesitaba, gracias!